# CURL handle goes Stale when inside foreach()

Tags: r

Alright, so I've recently figured out that I can query a website behind a login screen for a CSV Report.  Then I thought, wouldn't it be even better to do this concurrently?  Afterall some reports take a lot longer to produce than others and if I were querying 10 different reports at once that would be way more efficient.  So I'm now over my head twice here playing around with HTTPS protocols and now also Parallel Processing.  I think my frankencode is almost there though but it gives me a

```
"Error in ( : task 1 failed - "Stale CURL handle being passed to libcurl"
```

Note that the "curl" is very much current as the "html" variable did login successfully.  Something happens in it's parallel chunk that makes it stale.

```
library(RCurl)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=4)

agent="Firefox/23.0" 

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(
  cookiejar = 'cookies.txt' ,
  useragent = agent,
  followlocation = TRUE ,
  autoreferer = TRUE ,
  curl = curl
)
un="username@domain.com"
pw="password"

html = postForm(paste("https://login.salesforce.com/?un=", un, "&pw=", pw, sep=""), curl=curl)


urls = c("https://xyz123.salesforce.com/00O400000046ayd?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv", 
         "https://xyz123.salesforce.com/00O400000045sWu?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv", 
         "https://xyz123.salesforce.com/00O400000045z3Q?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv")

x <- foreach(i=1:4, .combine=rbind, .packages=c("RCurl")) %dopar% {
  xxx <- getURL(urls[i], curl=curl)
}
```

Comment: Try doing async=TRUE in the getURL.
afaik RCurl is not threadsafe, but this might work for you.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Perhaps there's a better way to go about this?  Is there a more threadsafe way?  I've played with the getURIAsynchronous() function but it doesn't seem to work either.  I have a MASSIVE report that I want to get, but I figured if I broke the report up into 10 chunks and query all 10 chunks at once it might download up to 10x faster